# How to control windows without titles?

Tags: vba

When a window has no title, how can we know the name of it to control it with script?

The window "Start" without a title.

[image]

This is a window appearing when we work with  the software "SnagIt". Because window "Start" has no title, so I don't know how to use a script to move or resize the window. Please help me!

Comment: See https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2019/05/winlistexe-list-open-windows-and-their.html